# Bad audit for Close votes review

Tags: support, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just stumbled upon [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4412494) - it is not programming related, it is not about browsers and the tags are all wrong - it is not a question for SO. I obviously hit **Close** and it shows as failed audit.

Please downvote it / remove it from audits. I also flagged it for moderators, but don't know how much that helps.

Comment: Voted to close that one as off-topic. It is not a programming question.

Comment: `[status-completed]`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Excelent.